# Migrating MongoDB of Parse results in lost of connection

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

After Parse communicated the close of it in the next year, they recommended to do some steps to migrate from their API / hosted MongoDB database to your server.

Basically I'm in this step:

[image]

To do this I followed the [next tutorial](http://julienrenaux.fr/2016/01/29/complete-parse-server-migration-guide/), the steps **Migrate Parse DB** and **Transfer Data**.

Now my data is complete, but I can't use my app anymore. These are the latest logs I can see, it doesn't connect or respond:

[image]

so briefly I'm just migrating the Parse DB by now,

did I skip any step and that's why it's not working?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

I've seen two requests of closing, because it's "unclear", I'm trying to figure out how to proceed, because following the tutorial mentioned above or the one on [Parse Blog](https://parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating). After following those steps, I can't get my app working due to the errors mentioned above.

Am I asking wrong?

Thank you ;)

Comment: I don't understand still why people mark it to close.

Please, don't migrate your Parse database yet!! it's bugged as @Niraj-shah mentioned. Follow that thread to check if it works or not

Comment: have you also copied across your cloud code functions to the server?

Comment: @cloudgroup it's supposed to work without those files, it's the step 3, and I'm in the step 1 (migrating only the db)... must I copy them? where should I copy them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a bug with the migration tool, which is not migrating data correctly. The Parse team are currently working on it.

Issue reported here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/42